# Integration testing maven plugins

Tags: integration-testing, maven-plugin

There are five choices listed in the [maven documentation on testing maven plugins](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/plugin-testing.html):

- maven-verifier
- maven-invoker-plugin
- shitty-maven-plugin
- maven-it-plugin
- maven-plugin-management-plugin

I've tried a few of these and had a number of problems:

- *maven-verifier* appears to have only a limited set of verifications -- I need to be able to make arbitrary assertions
- *shitty-maven-plugin* [has a bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSHITTY-33) that prevents it working with maven 3
- nethier *maven-plugin-management-plugin* nor *maven-it-plugin* are stable and don't seem to be under active development

Is anyone able to recommend any of these plugins?  Can you provide some example configuration?

Comment: I've just stumbled upon maven's [plugin-testing](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-testing/), so I'll take a look at that, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best thing i can recommend is the [maven-invoker-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/), cause it's can handle many situations and produces a real maven environment with all things which you really need to do integration test in relationship with Maven Plugins.

Comment: This will let me run a goal on any pom.  I just need to work out how to stage the plugin before executing the invoker.

Comment: You can localy install the plugin during an integration test.

Comment: The maven-invoker-plugin has an example on it pages how to do this: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/examples/install-artifacts.html